# sudo apt can't install packages

Tags: fedora, apt

I recently switched to Fedora.

`sudo apt install` doesn't work, as any package I try cannot be found.

I tried the following:

node, nodejs, build-essentials, python, python2, python3

all of which gave me: Unable to locate package [package name]

How can I install packages?

Comment: Not about programming means not on-topic for SO. Try the Unix/Linux or Super User sibling sites. But when posting there, add how you "recently switched", what you switched from, what you did before `sudo apt install` (did you `sudo apt update`?), etc.

Comment: Fedora doesn't use `apt` by default. Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/package-management/)? In any case, as underscore_d says this is off-topic here. Try [su] (but make sure to read their on-topic guidelines and ask a good question if you're going to post there).

Comment: Thanks, underscore_d and Chris will do next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APT is a package manager for Debian-based systems, and Fedora is Red-Hat-based.

All Red-Hat-based systems use the RPM-based package manager. Thus you should be able to install packages using either `yum` (for all Red-Hat systems) or `dnf` (for Fedora only).

Try using the below command to install packages

```
sudo yum install <package-name>
```

or

```
sudo dnf install <package-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fedora uses RPM, not APT. The docs are here:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system

Here are the installation docs for node on Fedora:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#centos-fedora-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux